# My auto-generated doctrine file still includes and executes previous migrations commands

Tags: database, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have a problem with how doctrine migration files are generated in my Symfony 4 app. My understanding is that each migration file should contain only the changes made since the last migration file was generated. For example, if I only made a small change in my Entity class e.g User class by only adding the age property I should expect that when I run **make: migration** in my console the only thing that my new migration file will contain is the command to add a Age column in my User Table. However, in my situation, the newer auto-generated file also contains older commands from a previous migration version which also get executed. Is there a way I could get rid of the older commands being included in my new migration file?
I'm running the latest Symfony 4.3 with Doctrine2

Comment: did you run run previous migrations (`bin/console doctrine:migrations:migrate`) before generate new migration?

Comment: Yes...I did. The problem started when I manually updated my development LAMP.

Comment: did you try also `bin/console doctrine:schema:update --dump-sql` to check the output

Comment: Yeah...it outputs previous migration version commands

Comment: Migrations are maintained by a `migration_versions` table.  Check and see if it's set to the proper version.  `doctrine:migrations:diff` is pretty good about finding differences in the DB vs Entities.  It really sounds like your DB is behind and those migrations need to be run to get it up to date.

Comment: Thanks let me check